# How can I plot the number of buyers and sellers in tradingview using pine script?

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to display the number of buyers and sellers on the chart which keeps updating itself every candle?

Answer (score 0):

No. Pine scripts do not have access to individual transactions—only their aggregate.

Comment: Thanks. The aggregate would be helpful too. How do I do that?

Comment: By *aggregate* I meant the resulting price/volume data available with the `close` and `volume` variables in Pine. Sorry for the confusion.